# How to do the 3D fourier transformation of the following equation?

Tags: fourier-transform, gaussian

Three-dimensional (3D) cylindrically-shaped function (Its axis passes through the origin with orientation vector sin  0 cos  and the intensity distribution of its cross-section has isotropic 2D Gaussian function.):

$$G(x,y,z;σ) =\frac{1}{2πσ^2}exp(-\frac{{x_a}^2+{y_a}^2}{2σ^2})$$

$$ {x_a}=xcosθ-zsinθ$$
$$ {y_a} =y$$

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0yGi.png)

I try to use the method I used in 1D and 2D Fourier transformation, but it seems that it doesn't work. I can't get rid of the complex number i in this fourier transformation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos
I try to use the method I used in Fourier transformation of 1D and 2D Guassian Function , but it seems that it doesn't work. I can't get rid of the complex number i in this fourier transformation.

Comment: @md2perpe
Thank you for your advice, the link you sent me help me a lot!